# Getting COUNT of Specific set of Customers - MySQL Query - Is there a faster way?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a custom report right now. It involves running this query over 50 times for different date conditions.

Anyway, this report revolves around two tables:

`agreement`
(a list of customer promised to pay - tied to `customer` table by `customer.id = agreement.customer_id`)

```
|----|-------------|---------------------|--------|----------|  
| id | customer_id |  entered_timestamp  | amount | campaign |  
|----|-------------|---------------------|--------|----------|  
| 1  |     123     | 2015-12-22 13:12:00 |   30   |   'xyz'  |  
|----|-------------|---------------------|--------|----------|  
| 2  |     400     | 2015-12-22 13:15:00 |   20   |   'abc'  |  
|----|-------------|---------------------|--------|----------|
```

`previous_customer_ids`
(a list of customer ids that have at least one paid agreement - tied to `customer` table by `customer.id = previous_customer_ids.customer_id`)

```
|----|-------------|  
| id | customer_id |  
|----|-------------|  
| 1  |     123     |  
|----|-------------|
```

I am trying to get a count of all unique `customer_id`s whose most recent agreement was in jan or july for a certain campaign and also exist in `previous_customer_ids`.

I was able to figure out how to get a list of each customer's most recent agreement who exists in `previous_customer_id`s, and get a count of that number of customers.

However, the query takes 35 seconds to run. I have to run it 60 times over each time this report is pulled (using php to display the results).

```
select count(t1.customer_id) 
from agreement t1  
inner join (  
  select customer_id, max(entered_timestamp) as latestOrder 
  from agreement  
  where campaign = 'vsf' 
  group by customer_id  
) t2  
inner join previous_customer_ids pcids  
        on t1.customer_id = pcids.customer_id  
where t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id  
  AND t1.entered_timestamp= t2.latestOrder  
  AND (substr(t1.entered_timestamp,6,2) = '01'  
    OR substr(t1.entered_timestamp,6,2) = '07')
```

How to optimize this?

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)
Also Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Thank you Juan Carlos - I'm working on this now!

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza hope you would not mind me copying your comment.

Comment: @e4c5 no problem, I have several on my notepad depending on the situation. There are very common response to help new users.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks. I've got a couple of others I picked up like this. And two or three of my own

Comment: did you search it? if yes, what have you found?